# Is it possible to use checkbox inside a button?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have some Buttons instead of using a ListView , so I would like to add a CheckBox to each of the Buttons, but I don't know how to.
As you already know, a CheckBox itself is a Button.

At this point  I'm confused: I have no idea on how to make it

Here is an example of what I want it to be like:

[image]

If you could help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you use layout instead.

Comment: No, because a Button is a View, not a ViewGroup (a container). On the other hand, a CheckBox is already a Button. You can customize its aspect to make it look like a button. For your [reference](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)

Comment: ViewGroup extends View, so you won't have any problems with it.

Comment: @EnderMuab'Dib Then try putting a CheckBox inside a RadioButton... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will just give you some general guidelines here, as the question is broad.

As you know, `CheckBox` itself inherits from `Button`. This means that you just need to make a check box "looks" like a button to meet the requirement. And all you need to do is extending the `CheckBox` class

```
public class CheckBoxButton extends CheckBox {

}
```

Of course you need to implement the constructors and stuff. And the most important thing that you need to do is to override `onDraw`. In there, you can draw a border around it. And maybe draw a shadow to make it 3D. You can do everything to make it look like a button.

More information on custom drawing here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Alternatively, you can find a library to do this. [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com) is a good place to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a LinearLayout with a TextView and an empty CheckBox. Since you are using a ListView you should add an OnItemClickListener to your Adapter to handle the click in each View, so you don't need to use a button.

If you really need/want to use a Button, use a FrameLayout instead for each item in the list, so the checkbox can be above the button. Something like (not tested):

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

Comment: This will add a ViewGroup and another View. Which is not very good for performances.